# How do I check the version of NeoVim in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I can check vim's version by using `v:version`, 
and I can check if I am running in nvim by doing `has('nvim')`.  Is there a variable like `v:version` in neovim to let me know the nvim version, like `0.1.4` or `0.1.6`?

Comment: Are you testing for a Neovim-only feature?  If so, you can just use `has('feature')` or `has('*function_name')`. If not, you can still use `has("patch-7.4.123")` to see if what you need is available. I made the plugin [helpful.vim](https://github.com/tweekmonster/helpful.vim) which can help you find the version numbers you would want to test.

Comment: As of 0.1.6, you will be able to check `has('nvim-1.2.3')`

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned in comments elsewhere, you can use `has`. For generic "is this neovim":

```
:echo has('nvim')
```

For at least minor version `0.1` (latest as of this writing):

```
:echo has('nvim-0.1')
```

For at least patch version `0.1.6`:

```
:echo has('nvim-0.1.6')
```

Answer (score 9):

There is probably a direct way (?); if not, here's a function that parses `:version` to extract and return the actual value (as string):

```
function! GetNVimVersion()
    redir => s
    silent! version
    redir END
    return matchstr(s, 'NVIM v\zs[^\n]*')
endfunction
```

.. so that you can show it with: `echo GetNVimVersion()` or store it in some variable.

Comment: Actually, with `execute()`, this can be more compact: `let version = matchstr(execute('version'), 'NVIM v\zs[^\n]*')`.  But, the function was added in nvim 0.1.5 and vim 7.4.2008

Comment: That's good to know, thanks! Although a little ironic in this case - since the version isn't known, adding another branch for this situation - `if exists('*execute')` - actually makes the code bigger (since you can't rely on the function to exist in your (n)vim - for some time, at least).

Comment: From what I noticed, Neovim users tend to upgrade to the latest stable release since they're responsible for accessing distribution channels. Once it's in official package repositories, the problem you mentioned will be a more concrete reality when a version is frozen for a stable OS release.  If I'm reading it right, [Neovim 0.1.5 will be available in Debian Stretch](https://jamessan.com/~jamessan//posts/neovim-enters-stretch/).

Comment: Sure, if I'd need the version number myself, I'd certainly use your `execute()`-based one liner (because I know what I install).

Comment: It was just a thought about figuring out a baseline version if you really had to. The point is moot since the only good reason you'd want to get the version is to print it. I think there are better ways to test capabilities as I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: Thanks, is it reliable enough ? If the output pattern changes some day, it may not work any more.

Comment: Well, at least you will know that something is wrong ... from the returned result string (you can verify its format) :)

Comment: The only caveat is that "version" is a readonly variable, so we have to asign to another variable name [@Tommy A](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/5229/tommy-a)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get the version, instead of just checking if the editor is a specific patch, just use `v:lua.vim.version()`. That is a special variable that can call into the Lua scripting functions, and just returns a Dictionary (vimscript's associative array). Use `:echo v:lua.vim.version()` in command mode to see its values.

Example use:

```
if v:lua.vim.version().major == 0 && v:lua.vim.version().minor < 8
  " Run this only on older versions.
endif
```